# print the null and empty list in the dictionary from an api call

Tags: python, string, list, api, dictionary

my code below is an API call and this is the output.

output:

```
{
  "name": "py",
  "title": "Py",
  "description": "Python",
  "url": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": [
    {
      "name": "team"
    }
  ],
  "repo": "https://github",
  "sub": null,
  "open": null,
  "url": [],
  "username": null,
  "deprecated": false,
  "replace": null,
  "exp": false,
  "for": [
    "*"
  ]}
```

my code:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        resp = response.json()
        if resp.values() == 'null' and len(resp.values()) == 0:
            print(resp['annotations'])
    else:
        print(response.status_code)
```

the resp is the output of the API call and I need it to be in a nested dictionary in a list with the condition of is the value is an empty list or has a null value and I do not know how to go about it

Comment: `response.json()` will parse the Json response to dictionary. No need to convert it back to string with `json.dumps()`

Comment: Use the `pprint` module to print the dictionary with nice formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is a valid format of dictionary you may use the `json.load(<string>)` function.
Don't forget to insert the `import json` line.

Comment: hi @Vittoriobarbera. I made a mistake with the question. i edited it now